# jqGrid - Unique ID for new row

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am trying to asign a unique ID to the new rows i add to my jqGrid. I use free jqGrid 4.11.0, a java rest service for the server side and MS SQL for databases.

```
inlineEditing: {

    ajaxSaveOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    serializeSaveData: function (postData) {

        var idArray = grid.getCol('id');
        var count = 0;
        var k = 1;

            while(postData.id.search('jqg') != '-1'){

                for(var i =0 ; i<idArray.length;i++){

                    if(k == idArray[i]){
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(count == 0){

                        postData.id = k  ;
                        break;                              
                    }
                }                       
                k++;
            }               
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    }
}
```

I noticed the default ID given by jqGrid is jqg + a number. Any suggestions on how i could make a unique ID thats not currently in use on any of the database records? Should i do this from the server side or it can be made in the jqGrid code?

At some point in the evening, this code was kind of working and kept on giving id 7 to all new rows [even though it should have kept on increasing]. After some changes[cant remember what changes], every time i click save to submit the new row to the server, the page freezes and chrome suggest i should kill the process.

Please let me know what and if i should add more information.

Edit1 :

```
$(function () {

var grid = $('#grid'),
    checkboxEditOptionEvents = [

        {type : 'click', data: {'Yes': 'Yes'}, fn: function (e, id) {
            var checkboxCol = grid.getCol('sefDepartament'),
                ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs'),
                numberOfCheckedBoxes = [],
                k;

            for (k = 0; k < ids.length; k++) {
                    if(checkboxCol[k] == 'Yes'){
                        numberOfCheckedBoxes.push(checkboxCol[k]);
                        if (numberOfCheckedBoxes.length == 1){
                            alert('Please deselect the other checked box first');
                            $(this).prop("checked",false);
                            numberOfCheckedBoxes = 0;
                        }
                    }
        }
    }}];

var experienceFunction = function(cellvalue, options ,rowObject){

            var joinYearVar =  rowObject.joinYear,
             YY = joinYearVar.slice(0,4),
             MM = joinYearVar.slice(5,7),
             DD= joinYearVar.slice(8,11);

            return moment("\"" +YY+MM+DD+"\"" , "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();

};

var checkboxFormatFunc = function(cellvalue, options ,rowObject){
    if(cellvalue == 'Yes'){
        return 'Yes';
    }
    return 'No';
};

var  afterSaveFunction =   function(id){

            var prenumeVar = grid.getCell(id, 'prenume').trim(),
                numeVar = grid.getCell(id,'nume').trim(),
                usernameVar =  numeVar +'.'+ prenumeVar,
                emailVar = usernameVar + '@test.com';
            usernameVar =usernameVar.replace(/\s/g , '').trim();
            emailVar = emailVar.replace(/\s/g , '');

            grid.setCell(id, 'username', usernameVar);
            grid.setCell(id, 'email', emailVar);

};

var colModelSettings = [

    {name:'id', label:'id',key: true,hidden: true, width:10,sorttype:'number',editable: false},     
    {name:'nume',label:'Nume',width:90, align: 'center',editable:true,searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','bw','ew','cn']}, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions: {defaultValue: ' '},formatter: 'text'},
    {name:'prenume',label:'Prenume',width:100,editable:true,searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','bw','ew','cn']},align: 'center',editrules:{required:true},editoptions: {defaultValue: ' '},formatter: 'text'},
    {name:'username',label:'Username',searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','bw','ew','cn']},width:125,align: 'center'  },
    {name:'email',label:'Email',width:135,searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','bw','ew','cn']},align: 'center'},
    {name:'sefDepartament',label:'Sef Departament',width:90,editable:true,align: 'center', stype:"select", searchoptions:{sopt: ['eq','ne'],value: "Yes:Yes;No:No"},formatter: checkboxFormatFunc,edittype:'checkbox',editoptions: { dataEvents: checkboxEditOptionEvents,value:'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'No' }},
    {name:'position',label:'Position',editable:true,stype: 'select',formatter: 'select',searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','ne'],value: ' : ;position 1:position 1;position 2:position 2;position 3:position 3;position 4:position 4;position 5:position 5'},
    align: 'center',edittype:'select',editoptions:{defaultvalue: 'P0: ',value: ' : ;position 1:position 1;position 2:position 2;position 3:position 3;position 4:position 4;position 5:position 5'},width: 75},

    {name:'joinYear',label:'Join Year',formatter:'date', formatoptions: {newformat:'d-m-Y'}, datefmt: 'dd-mm-yyyy', editable:true,searchtype: 'datepicker',align: 'center',width: 70,
    searchoptions:{dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',dataInit: function (elem){
        $(elem).datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});},sopt: ['eq','ne']},

    editoptions:{size:20,defaultValue: ' ',dataInit: function (elem) {

        $(elem).datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true, dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
    }}},

    {name:'experience', label:'Experience', formatter: experienceFunction, searchoptions:{sopt: ['eq','bw','ew','cn']}, editable:'hidden', editoptions:{defaultValue: ' '},align: 'center',width: 60},
    {name:'actiuni',label: 'Actiuni',formatter: 'actions', formatoptions: {afterSave:afterSaveFunction},editable: false,sortable: false,search: false,width: 20 }
    ];

grid.jqGrid({

    pager: '#pager', 
    url: "/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/fetchData",
    editurl:'/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/update',
    datatype: "json",
    height: 250,    
    viewrecords: true,
    scrollOffset:0,
    sortorder: 'asc', 
    caption:'Employee List' ,
    autowidth: true,
    colModel: colModelSettings,
    beforeSelectRow : function(id){ 

                        var idsArray = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                        var i;
                        for(i=0;i<idsArray.length;i++){
                            if($('#'+idsArray[i]).is('[editable="1"]') ){
                            grid.editRow(idsArray[i],true);
                            return false;
                            }
                        }   
                        return true;
                    },

    inlineEditing: {

        ajaxSaveOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        serializeSaveData: function (postData) {

            var idArray = grid.getCol('id');
            var count = 0;
            var k = 1;

                while(postData.id.search('jqg') != '-1'){

                    for(var i =0 ; i<idArray.length;i++){

                        if(k == idArray[i]){

                            count++;
                        }
                        if(count == 0){

                            postData.id = k  ;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    k++;
                }

            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        }
    }
});


grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {edit:false, add:false, delete:true, save:false, cancel:false, search:true, searchtext: 'Search', refresh:true},

        {},{},{     
                url: '/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/delete',
                mtype: 'DELETE',
                reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                ajaxDelOptions: {
                    contentType: "application/json",
                },
                serializeDelData: function(postdata) {

                    return JSON.stringify(postdata);

            }},{},{},{},{} );

grid.jqGrid('inlineNav','#pager',
{
    edit:true,
    edittext: 'Edit',
    save:true,
    savetext: 'Save',
    add:true,
    cancel: true,
    canceltext: 'Cancel',
    cancelicon: 'ui-icon-cancel',
    addicon:'ui-icon-plus',
    addtext: 'Add',
    addedrow: 'last',
    addParams: {

        position: 'last',
        addRowParams: { 

            aftersavefunc : afterSaveFunction,
            keys: true,
        }
            },
    editParams:{

        url: '/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/update',
        mtype : "POST",
        keys: true,
        aftersavefunc : afterSaveFunction,
    }
})})
```

Edit2 - Server Responce to fetchData :

```
[{"id":"3","nume":"Aladin","prenume":"Zoro","username":"Aladin.Zoro","email":"Aladin.Zoro@test.com","sefDepartament":"Yes","position":"position 4","joinYear":"2015-11-08","experience":"2 months"},

{"id":"2","nume":"Harap","prenume":"Alb","username":"Harap.Alb","email":"Harap.Alb@test.com","sefDepartament":"No","position":"position 1","joinYear":"2016-01-03","experience":"9 days  "},

{"id":"4","nume":"Don","prenume":"Homa","username":"Don.Homa","email":"Don.Homa@test.com","sefDepartament":"No","position":"position 4","joinYear":"2015-09-06","experience":"4 months"},

{"id":"5","nume":"Dorel","prenume":"Gigel","username":"Dorel.Gigel","email":"Dorel.Gigel@test.com","sefDepartament":"No","position":"position 4","joinYear":"2016-01-10","experience":"2 days"},

{"id":"1","nume":"Ivan","prenume":"Stefan","username":"Ivan.Stefan","email":"Ivan.Stefan@test.com","sefDepartament":"No","position":"position 2","joinYear":"2016-01-10","experience":"2 days"}]
```

Comment: I suppose that you try to solve some problem which exist only because of other settings which you made. You wrote about MS SQL. You should should have at least one table where you need to add new record. How is the primary key defined in the database? One have typically `IDENTITY` column `Id` defined like `Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`. Thus the database generate the value. How you defined jqGrid? Which `colModel` you use? If you don't have `id` column then you have no problem. You can just reload jqGrid from the server after adding new rows and you will have id generated by server.

Comment: Hello, Oleg! I have a ID column in jqgrid and i also have a ID column [PK] in MS SQL table where i get my data from and where i send the new information. I was not aware of the IDENTITY function of a table column. If i were to set IDENTITY to a table column, the DB would automaticly generate the ID from what i understand but if i were to add a new row it would have a ID thats generated by the DB and a local ID generated by jqGrid before it refreshes and a edit on the new row would not be processed. How could i fix that? Would a jqGrid reload trigger after row post take care of it?

Comment: **Could you include some JavaScript code which you use and an example of JSON format which you use for the communication with the server?** The `int IDENTITY` in MS SQL (or `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySQL) is the best choice for the primary key in my opinion. jqGrid first create the *temporary local* rowid, but it can update it after receiving the response from the server. There are many ways to update ids. The best choice depend on *what you implement*. If you display the grid for editing and allows the user to create new row then reloading would be the best choice.

Comment: If you displays an empty grid and the user need to fill many rows one after another then the reloading of the grid could be not the best choice and you should implement updating the rowid inside of `aftersavefunc` callback. The server should return the new rowid in the response of `editurl` and the callback `aftersavefunc` should use something like `$("#" + rowid).attr("id", newRowid)` to update the rowid. The exact code can depend on `colModel` which you use and from the format of the server response. You can use `rowversion` (`timestamp`) column for the concurrence check and update it too.

Comment: I added my entire jqGrid code. I understand both of the ideeas and i will make sure to try both. I am confident i will get it working. At the moment the SQL server is down and i cant get a server produced JSON sample. You can post a answer if you wish  so i can set it as correct. As soon as the server is back up ill get started on workin on it. Thank you!

Comment: I'll post my answer soon, but some settings looks a little strange. **Could you add the format of data returned from `/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/fetchData`? Do you implemented server side paging? How many rows of data you need to display/edit (10, 100, 1000, 100000)?** I see `pager`, but no `rowNum` and I see `height: 250` instead. Do you return 20 rows from the server and use server side paging? It seems that you use **the same** `'/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/update'` for both Edit and Add new rows. You have to do different things in the case. Why you don't implement separate URLs?

Comment: Server is back up, so i will add the server response to the fetchData class. This is just a simple project with the main focus on creating functionality and connection from jqGrid to DB. I have very few records. I made a method at rest/update that performs different actions depending on the oper value in the POST request.

Comment: I have fixed my issue by generating the ID using IDENTITY as you suggested and entered a reload grid trigger in aftersavefunc. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome! I still posted my answer with some additional tips to you. I hope it could be helpful for other developers who uses free jqGrid.

Comment: I am sure it will! Thanks, ill make sure to apply the suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are some advises to solve your main problem and to improve the JavaScript code which you posted.

First of all, the generation of new rowids *locally* is required for local editing scenario. One should generate the new rowids *on the server* in case of saving the data on the backend in the database. Typical implementation consist on having `PRIMARY KEY` defined as `int IDENTITY` in *every* table. It makes the ids unique and fixed. Deleting of some row and creating the new one will never be interpreted as editing of the old row because the new row will get always new id, which was never used before (in the table).

To have advantage of ids generated on the *server side* one have two main choices:

1. reloading the grid after every Add row operation.
2. extending the communication with the server on editing so, that the server returns new id, generated in the database table, back to jqGrid. One can use `aftersavefunc` callback (for Add new row only) for updating the rowid after successful creating the row on the server. Many standard implementations of RESTful services returns back *full row data* inclusive id on both Add or Edit. One can use the data inside of `aftersavefunc` callback and use something like `$("#" + rowid).attr("id", newRowid);` to update the new row. It one saved the id in some additional columns (like you use hidden `id` column) then one should use `setCell` method additionally to update the cell too.

The first choice is the mostly simple and I would recommend you to implement it first of all. Only if reloading of the grid will not satisfy the users, who  add many rows one after another, then you should write a little more code and to implement the second scenario.

You current code use `inlineNav` for Add and Edit operations, implemented using inline editing, and the method `navGrid` for Delete operation, implemented using form editing. The form editing, inclusive Delete, uses `reloadAfterSubmit: true` option by default. It means that the grid will be reloaded from the server (from `url: "/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/fetchData"`) after deleting of every row. You can solve your main problem by replacing `afterSaveFunction` to the following:

```
var afterSaveFunction = function () {
        $(this).trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true, fromServer: true}]);
    };
```

The option `current` to hold the current selection after reloading and the option `fromServer: true` have sense only in case if you use `loadonce: true` option additionally. You can just use `reloadGridOptions: {fromServer: true}` option of `navGrid` to force reloading the data *from the server* on click on the Refresh/Reload button of the navigator bar. If you have not so much data which you need to display in the grid (for example less as 1000 of rows) then such behavior would be recommended.

Some more common advices to you to improve your code:

You can consider to use `height: "auto"` instead of `height: 250` and to manage the maximal height of the grid by specifying `rowNum` value. The option `scrollOffset: 0` will be unneeded in the case.

The format of the data returned from the server looks so, that you **don't implemented server side paging, sorting and filtering**. You should use `loadonce: true` and `forceClientSorting: true` options. The `loadonce: true` informs jqGrid to save *all* the data returned from the server locally in internal `data` parameter. You can any time access the array by usage `$('#grid').jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")`. The value of `rowNum` (the default value is 20) will be used for *local* paging. The `sortname` and the `sortorder` will be used for *local* sorting. And you will use searching dialog (added by `navGrid`) or the filter toolbar (added by `filterToolbar`) for *local* searching/filtering. It simplify the server code, improve the performance of the grid from the user's point of view, and simplifies the interface between the server and the client. You can use the classical RESTful interface on the server without any extensions.

Another remark: I'd recommend you to remove unneeded hidden `id` column (`name:'id', label:'id', key: true, hidden: true, ...`). The information about the rowid will be saved in `id` attribute of the rows (`<tr>` element) and one don't need to hold duplicate information in the hidden `<td>` element in every row.

There are many other parts of your code, which could be improved. For example the DELETE operation which you use on the server side seems be strange. You use `mtype: 'DELETE'`, but you send the id of deleted row inside of *body* of the request to the server instead of appending it to the URL. Corresponds to the standards, the HTTP DELETE should contains *no body*. You can use jqGrid option `formDeleting` to specify all Delete options and you can define `url` parameter as function:

```
formDeleting: {
    mtype: "DELETE",
    url: function (rowid) {
        return "/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/delete/" + rowid;
    },
    ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    serializeDelData: function () {
        return "";
    }
}
```

You need of cause modify your server code of `/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/delete/` to use the same communication protocol and to get the id of deleted from from the URL.

You can use `navOptions` parameter of free jqGrid to specify the options of `navGrid`:

```
navOptions: { edit: false, add: false }
```

(`searchtext: 'Search'` and other options which you use seems to have default values and I removed there).

To be closer to REST standards one can use HTTP PUT operation for row editing and HTTP POST for adding new rows. You should implement *different* entry points for both operation on the backend. You use `/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/update` already and you can implement `/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/create` for adding new rows. You can use the following `inlineEditing` changes for example to implement the scenario:

```
inlineNavOptions: { add: true, edit: true },
inlineEditing: {
    url: function (id, editOrAdd) {
        return "/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/" +
            (editOrAdd === "edit" ? "update" : "create");
    },
    mtype: function (editOrAdd) {
        return editOrAdd === "edit" ? "PUT" : "POST";
    },
    keys: true,
    serializeSaveData: function (postData) {
        return JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
    },
    aftersavefunc: function () {
        $(this).trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true, fromServer: true}]);
    },
    addParams: {
        addRowParams: {
            position: "last",
            serializeSaveData: function (postData) {
                var dataToSend = $.extend({}, postData);
                // don't send any id in case of creating new row
                // or to send `0`:
                delete dataToSend.id; // or dataToSend.id = 0; 
                return JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
            }
        }
    }
}
```