# setting delete options in jqgrid using extend is not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to use a rest service with jqgrid according to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344310/using-jqgrids-inline-editing-with-restful-urls) and I want to set "DELETE" metod for all my grids, but jqgrid still uses POST as the method for sending delete requests. This how I'm doing it:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.del, {
mtype: "DELETE"});
```

and this is my grid instance delete options in navGrid:

```
{
    url: '../../webresources/routing/phoneNumber',

    serializeDelData: function () {
        return ""; // don't send and body for the HTTP DELETE
    },
    onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
        params.url += '/' + encodeURIComponent(postdata);
    },
    errorTextFormat: function (data) {
        return 'Error: ' + data.responseText;
    }
}
```

If I set mtype:"DELETE" in navGrid delete options it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you placed the statement `$.extend($.jgrid.del, { mtype: "DELETE"});` on the wrong place. Moreover it's dangerous to use non-deep version of `$.extend`. I'd recommend you to use

```
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.del, { mtype: "DELETE"});
```

instead. Moreover you can place `mtype: "DELETE"` **directly in the list of delete options** in `navGrid`.

**Please write always, in all your questions, which version of jqGrid and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use.** I develop free jqGrid fork since more as one year and have implemented a lot of new features. Some from new features simplifies the usage of RESTful services. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34721322/315935), which shows how one can use `url` defined as function for Delete operation and to use `url` and `mtype` defined as function for Add/Edit.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I was using guriddo's version of jqgrid (5.0.1) because it supports bootsrap. I pulled your repository and now it is working as expected. Is it possible to use bootstrap to style your version of jqgrid?
Thank you for your good work

Comment: @babak: You are welcome! The latest version (4.12.2-pre), which you can download from GitHub is not final, but you can download it and to use new `guiStyle: "bootstrap"` option. It works currently in combination with `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` only. You could include both `bootstrap.css` and `font-awesome.css` on the HTML page, but including `jquery-ui.css` is not required. **See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-bootstrap1.htm)**. I'm still working on the 4.12.2-pre, thus some features are not full finished.

Comment: @babak: I'll include support of Bootsrtap with `iconSet: "glyphicon"` (Bootstrap without Font Awesome) after the main part with `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` will be finished.