# delete on multiple jqGrids in singe page MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have two jqGrids in a single view. I got no problem in loading those grids, but when I am trying to delete records from grid1, it was posting to the URL set in grid2 delete method.

I was using below code to delete rows in two jqGrids.

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.del, {
    mtype: "DELETE",
    serializeDelData: function () {
        return ""; // don't send and body for the HTTP DELETE
    },
    onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
        params.url = 'url' + postdata;
    },
    afterComplete: function (response, postdata, formid) {
    }
});
```

I wrote two separate methods to delete from respective grids and both methods are like above.

Please tell me how to perform delete operations on both jqgrids.

I think extend method to delete rows in grid1 is over loaded by the grid2 extend method.

Comment: Please include in all questions about jqGrid the information, which version you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.jgrid.del` defined **defaults** used by all jqGrids on the page. `$.extend` just combines the properties of the parameter (`mtype`, `serializeDelData`, `onclickSubmit` and `afterComplete`) with the properties with the same name which could exist in `$.jgrid.del`. Thus jqGrid uses the object `$.jgrid.del` **not during creating the grid, but during executing Delete operation** then the code like

```
$.extend($.jgrid.del, {...}); // first settings
$("#grid1").jqGrid({
    ...
}).jqGrid("navGrid");
$.extend($.jgrid.del, {...}); // the second settings
$("#grid2").jqGrid({
    ...
}).jqGrid("navGrid");
```

will use *only the second settings* of `$.jgrid.del`.

Thus you should to use `$.extend($.jgrid.del, {...});` to set **common** defaults on the page and to set other parameters separately:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.del, {
    mtype: "DELETE",
    serializeDelData: function () {
        return ""; // don't send and body for the HTTP DELETE
    }
});
$("#grid1").jqGrid({
    ...
}).jqGrid("navGrid", ....., { /*Del options*/
    onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
        params.url = 'url1' + postdata;
    }
});
$("#grid2").jqGrid({
    ...
}).jqGrid("navGrid", ....., { /*Del options*/
    onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
        params.url = 'url2' + postdata;
    }
});
```

If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which I develop, then you can specify Delete parameters inside of `formDeleting` option of jqGrid. Additionally, free jqGrid supports *functions* as the value of `url` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34721322/315935) for more details) and you can rewrite the above code as following

```
$.extend($.jgrid.del, {
    mtype: "DELETE",
    serializeDelData: function () {
        return ""; // don't send and body for the HTTP DELETE
    }
});
$("#grid1").jqGrid({
    ...
    formDeleting: {
        url: function (rowid) {
            return "url1/" + rowid;
        }
    }
}).jqGrid("navGrid");
$("#grid2").jqGrid({
    ...
    formDeleting: {
        url: function (rowid) {
            return "url2/" + rowid;
        }
    }
}).jqGrid("navGrid");
```

Of cause if you set `editurl` to the base URL in every grid then you could access it from `url` function and rewrite the code as below

```
$.extend($.jgrid.del, {
    mtype: "DELETE",
    serializeDelData: function () {
        return ""; // don't send and body for the HTTP DELETE
    },
    url: function (rowid, postData, options) {
        return options.url + rowid;
    }
});
$("#grid1").jqGrid({
    ...
    editurl: "url1/"
}).jqGrid("navGrid");
$("#grid2").jqGrid({
    ...
    editurl: "url2/"
}).jqGrid("navGrid");
```

Comment: in-line editing and deleting not working for me. I should follow same procedure or any other??

Comment: @Markandeyulu: What you do exactly and what is not working?